# Javascript conflicts to my css of Admin LTE theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, adminlte

I am using Admin Lte Theme and I used [this JS file](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js)  for my AJAX call below all JS file in this theme. When i add this file, it conflicts my CSS.
Toggle doesn't work .

Comment: Make sure you have your jquery file before your app js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adminlite seems to be JQuery dependent

If you place JQuery script tag above all the others you should get your toggle problem fixed.
for example

```
<!--First load jquery-->
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Then load admin LTE theme -->
<script src="path/to/adminlte/"></script>
```